# Make an anonymous inner class a lambda in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I need to modify my code with the goal of (I quote) "make an anonymous inner class a lambda".

I have a suggestion to solve this problem, but not knowing how lambdas work in Java I don't know how to apply the suggestion to my specific case, can someone help me?

This is the suggestion I have

This is the "wrong" version:

```
myCollection.stream().map(new Mapper<String,String>() {
      public String map(String input) {
          return new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
      }
});
```

And this is the "correct" version:

```
myCollection.stream().map(input -> new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString());
```

Now, the "wrong" version in my code is this:

```
Collections.sort(commits, new Comparator<GitCommit>() {
    // @Override
    public int compare(GitCommit c1, GitCommit c2) {
        return c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate());
        }
    });
```

What is the corresponding "correct" version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(commits, Comparator.comparing(GitCommit::getDate));
```

or even

```
commits.sort(Comparator.comparing(GitCommit::getDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
Collections.sort(commits, new Comparator<GitCommit>() {
    // @Override
    public int compare(GitCommit c1, GitCommit c2) {
        return c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate());
        }
    });
```

to

```
Collections.sort(commits, (c1, c2) -> c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate()));
```

You do not need to use `Collections.sort` you can simply call the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) default `method` [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), namely:

```
commits.sort((c1, c2) -> c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate()));
```

and simplified further by using *method reference* and the `interface` [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
commits.sort(Comparator.comparing(GitCommit::getDate));
```

About the List default sort method:

> default void  sort(Comparator<? super E> c) Sorts this list according
> to the order induced by the specified Comparator.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the method `map` requires `Function`. I assume it's *wrong* because of the `Mapper.` The code remains invalid as long as `Mapper` doesn't extend `Function`. This is a way to go:

```
interface Mapper<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {
    default R map(T t) {
        return apply(t);
    }
}
```

```
myCollection.stream().map(new Mapper<String,String>() {
    public String apply(String input) {
        return new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
    }
});
```

---

The second case is correct and I assume your goal is to pack the anonymous function to:

- A lambda expression:

  ```
  Collections.sort(commits, (c1, c2) -> c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate()));
  ```
- Or to a method reference:

  ```
  Collections.sort(commits, Comparator.comparing(GitCommit::getDate));
  ```